# How to interact with the UI when testing an application written by kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

The application is written by kivy.
I want to test a function via pytest, but in order to test that function, I need to initalize the object first, but the object needs something from the UI when initalizing, but I am at testing phase, so don't know how to retrieve something from the UI.

This is the class which has an error and has been handled

```
class SaltConfig(GridLayout):
    def check_phone_number_on_first_contact(self, button):
        s = self.instanciate_ServerMsg(tt)

        try:
            s.send()
        except HTTPError as err:
            print("[HTTPError] : " + str(err.code))
            return

        # some code when running without error

    def instanciate_ServerMsg():
        return ServerMsg()
```

This is the helper class which generates the ServerMsg object used by the former class.

```
class ServerMsg(OrderedDict):
    def send(self,answerCallback=None):
        #send something to server via urllib.urlopen
```

This is my tests code:

```
class TestSaltConfig:
    def test_check_phone_number_on_first_contact(self):
        myError = HTTPError(url="http://127.0.0.1", code=500,
                        msg="HTTP Error Occurs", hdrs="donotknow", fp=None)

    mockServerMsg = mock.Mock(spec=ServerMsg)
    mockServerMsg.send.side_effect = myError

    sc = SaltConfig(ds_config_file_missing.data_store)

    def mockreturn():
        return mockServerMsg

    monkeypatch.setattr(sc, 'instanciate_ServerMsg', mockreturn)
    sc.check_phone_number_on_first_contact()
```

I can't initialize the object, it will throw an AttributeError when initialzing since it needs some value from UI.

So I get stuck.

I tried to mock the object then patch the function to the original one, but won't work either since the function itself has has logic related to UI.

How to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a design flaw. Logic shouldn't depend on UI. One reason for that, is so you can test it in isolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an article about testing Kivy apps together with a simple runner - [KivyUnitTest](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KivyUnitTest). It works with `unittest`, not with `pytest`, but it shouldn't be hard to rewrite it, so that it fits your needs. In the article I explain how to "penetrate" the main loop of UI and this way you can happily go and do with button this:

```
button = <button you found in widget tree>
button.dispatch('on_release')
```

and many more. Basically you can do anything with such a test and you don't need to test each function independently. I mean... it's a good practice, but sometimes (mainly when testing UI), you can't just rip the thing out and put it into a nice 50-line test.

This way you can do exactly the same thing as a casual user would do when using your app and therefore you can even catch issues you'd have trouble with when testing the casual way e.g. some weird/unexpected user behavior.

Here's the skeleton:

```
import unittest

import os
import sys
import time
import os.path as op
from functools import partial
from kivy.clock import Clock

# when you have a test in <root>/tests/test.py
main_path = op.dirname(op.dirname(op.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(main_path)

from main import My


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def pause(*args):
        time.sleep(0.000001)

    # main test function
    def run_test(self, app, *args):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.pause, 0.000001)

        # Do something

        # Comment out if you are editing the test, it'll leave the
        # Window opened.
        app.stop()

    def test_example(self):
        app = My()
        p = partial(self.run_test, app)
        Clock.schedule_once(p, 0.000001)
        app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

However, as Tomas said, you should separate UI and logic when possible, or better said, when it's an *efficient* thing to do. You don't want to mock your whole big application just to test a single function that requires communication with UI.

Comment: How do you `wait_for` an element to appear ? Just poll the widget tree ? It's gonna be ineffective

Answer (score 1):

Finally made it, just get things done, I think there must be a more elegant solution. The idea is simple, given the fact that all lines are just simply value assignment except the `s.send()` statement.

Then we just mock the original object, every time when some errors pop up in the testing phase (since the object lack some values from the UI), we mock it, we repeat this step until the testing method can finally test if the function can handle the `HTTPError` or not.

In this example, we only need to mock a `PhoneNumber` class which is lucky, but some times we may need to handle more, so obviously @KeyWeeUsr 's answer is an more ideal choice for the production environment. But I just list my thinking here for somebody who wants a quick solution.

```
@pytest.fixture
def myHTTPError(request):
    """
    Generating HTTPError with the pass-in parameters 
    from pytest_generate_tests(metafunc)
    """
    httpError = HTTPError(url="http://127.0.0.1", code=request.param,
                          msg="HTTP Error Occurs", hdrs="donotknow", fp=None)
    return httpError

class TestSaltConfig:
    def test_check_phone_number( self, myHTTPError, ds_config_file_missing ):
        """
        Raise an HTTP 500 error, and invoke the original function with this error.
        Test to see if it could pass, if it can't handle, the test will fail.
        The function locates in configs.py, line 211
        This test will run 2 times with different HTTP status code, 404 and 500
        """

        # A setup class used to cover the runtime error
        # since Mock object can't fake properties which create via __init__()
        class PhoneNumber:
            text = "610274598038"

        # Mock the ServerMsg class, and apply the custom 
        # HTTPError to the send() method
        mockServerMsg = mock.Mock(spec=ServerMsg)
        mockServerMsg.send.side_effect = myHTTPError

        # Mock the SaltConfig class and change some of its 
        # members to our custom one
        mockSalt = mock.Mock(spec=SaltConfig)
        mockSalt.phoneNumber = PhoneNumber()
        mockSalt.instanciate_ServerMsg.return_value = mockServerMsg
        mockSalt.dataStore = ds_config_file_missing.data_store

        # Make the check_phone_number_on_first_contact() 
        # to refer the original function
        mockSalt.check_phone_number = SaltConfig.check_phone_number

        # Call the function to do the test
        mockSalt.check_phone_number_on_first_contact(mockSalt, "button")
```